# ¿Como puedo mostrar el titulo de una categoría y sus vuelos en js?

Tags: javascript

buenas a todos busco una ayuda para un codigo js, que es lo que busco  yo tengo mi barra de navegación con mis categorías y los registros que tiene  esa categoría , cuando esta en movil solo me aparece  la categoria que tengo seleccionada y me lo coloca con el  carrusel y eso lo que busco aunque no estén seleccionado la categoría en el formato movil que  muestre todas las categorías en una  forma de carrusel, el resultado que busco es que se muestre bien para que no seleccione el usuario y solo vea que lo que hay.

```
$(function() {
$('.cats-menu .nav-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let cat = $(this).data('cat');
    console.log(cat);
    const ele = $(this);
    
    $('.cats-menu .nav-link').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    ele.addClass('active');
    getFlightsByCat(cat);
});
$('.cats-menu .nav-item:nth-child(1) .nav-link').trigger('click');


});
function getFlightsByCat(cat) {
let dataCat = {'catId': cat};
console.log(dataCat);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataCat));
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/flights-by-cat',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataCat),
    success: response => {

        console.log(response.response.data);
        $('.main-flights .flights-container').html(response.response.data);
    },
    error: err => {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
}



$(function() {
$('.cats-menu .nav-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let cat = $(this).data('cat');
    console.log(cat);
    const ele = $(this);
    
    $('.cats-menu .nav-link').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    ele.addClass('active');
    getFlightsByCat(cat);
});
//  $('.cats-menu .nav-item:nth-child(1) .nav-link').trigger('click');


});

function getFlightsByCats(categories) {
let flights = [];

categories.forEach(cat => {
    let dataCat = {'catId': cat};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/flights-by-cat',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataCat),
        success: response => {
            flights.push(response.response.data);
        },
        error: err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});

return flights;
}

$('.cats-menu .nav-link').each(function(i, el) {
let cat = $(this).data('cat');

// En móvil, mostrar el título de la categoría y los vuelos
if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    $(this).append('<h2 class="cats-menu-title">' + cat + '</h2>');

    // Agrega el elemento `ul` a la barra de navegación
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.classList.add('cats-menu-flights');

    // Obtener los vuelos de la categoría
    let flightsCat = flights.filter(flights => flights.some(flight => flight.categoryId == cat));

    // Mostrar al menos 8 vuelos
    if (flightsCat.length > 8) {
        flightsCat = flightsCat.slice(0, 8);
    }

    flightsCat.forEach(flight => {
        // Agrega el vuelo al elemento `ul` correspondiente
        ul.append(flight);
    });

    // Agrega el código para el carrusel
    ul.slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });

    // Agrega el elemento `ul` a la barra de navegación
    $(this).append(ul);
}

// En PC, mostrar solo el título de la categoría
else {
    // Mostrar el título de la categoría y los vuelos
    $(this).append('<h2 class="cats-menu-title">' + flightsCat[0].categoryName + '</h2>');
}
});

// Mostrar los vuelos de la categoría seleccionada

$('.cats-menu .nav-link').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Obtener la categoría seleccionada
let cat = $(this).data('cat');

// Eliminar la clase `active` de todos los elementos `nav-link`
$('.cats-menu .nav-link').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});

// Agregar la clase `active` al elemento `nav-link` seleccionado
$(this).addClass('active');

// Obtener los vuelos de la categoría seleccionada
let flights = getFlightsByCats([cat]);

// Mostrar los vuelos en la página
if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    $('.main-flights .flights-container').html(flights);
} else {
    $('.main-flights .flights-container').html(flightsCat[0]);
}
});
```